# class, interface, or enum expected error in java

Tags: java

I keep getting this "class, interface, or enum expected" error in my code. Here is my code:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;


public class GradeAnalyzer
{

    public GradeAnalyzer ()
    {
    }

    public int getAverage (ArrayList<Integer> grades)
    {
       if (grades.size () < 1)
       {
            System.out.println ("Array List is empty");
            return 0;
        }
        else
        {
            int sum = 0;          
            for (int grade:grades)
            {           
                sum = sum + grade;
            } 
            int average = sum / grades.size ();
            System.out.println (average);
            return average;
        }
    }
}

public static void main (String[]args)
{
    ArrayList<Integer> myClassroom = new ArrayList<Integer> ();
    myClassroom.add (98);
    myClassroom.add (92);
    myClassroom.add (88);
    myClassroom.add (75);
    myClassroom.add (61);
    myClassroom.add (89);
    myClassroom.add (95);

    GradeAnalyzer myAnalyzer = new GradeAnalyzer ();
    myAnalyzer.getAverage (myClassroom);
}
```

Comment: Please indent your code

Comment: using a correct indentation could really help

Comment: Please post the complete stack trace / error text.

Comment: You need to use `for(Integer grade : grades)` . Also your average might be incorrect if you use integer division.

Comment: @Korashen it is a compile error. There is no stacktrace

Comment: @jr593 *You need to use for(Integer grade : grades)* Why?

Comment: According to the code you post, the main method is defined outside of a class

Comment: @Jens My point is, that the error message should be included in the post.

Comment: @Korashen it is *class, interface, or enum expected*

Comment: @Jens And in which line, does OP get this message?

Answer (score 2):

You should delete one curly brackets before main method and put it after main method. Your main method is out of the class currently.

Answer (score 1):

Your correct code should be:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class GradeAnalyzer {
    public int getAverage (ArrayList < Integer > grades)
    {
        if (grades.size () < 1)
        {
            System.out.println ("Array List is empty");
            return 0;
        } else {
            int sum = 0;
            for (int grade:grades)
            {
                sum = sum + grade;
            }
            int average = sum / grades.size ();
            System.out.println (average);
            return average;
        }
    }

    public static void main (String[]args)
    {
        ArrayList< Integer > myClassroom = new ArrayList < Integer > ();
        myClassroom.add (98);
        myClassroom.add (92);
        myClassroom.add (88);
        myClassroom.add (75);
        myClassroom.add (61);
        myClassroom.add (89);
        myClassroom.add (95);
        GradeAnalyzer myAnalyzer = new GradeAnalyzer ();
        myAnalyzer.getAverage (myClassroom);
    }
}
```

The reason you get error is your main method not inside class, you must put main method in to your class.